# Multilinear Regression:Interpreting " Insignificant" regressor Variables

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression

hope this is not too simple; please feel free to give me a reference if this is so. I want to know how to address having "insignificant" coefficients in my regression:

I just did a multilinear regression returning $y=a_1x_1+...+a_kx_k $

In the resulting analysis, two of the coefficients came

Answer (score 3):

Your note was not complete, but the short answer is that you don't need to look at the $p$-values at all to interpret the regression coefficients and standard errors.  A good approach, no matter what the significance, is to compute a confidence interval for an effect of interest, e.g., the effect of raising $x_3$ from 13 to 17.  In the special and somewhat unusual case where $x_3$ is linear and doesn't interact with anything, this effect is $4\beta_3$.

To carry out the contrast of interest when the effect is forced to be linear, get the estimate of $\beta_3$ and its estimated standard error and compute a confidence interval such as $4\hat{\beta} \pm 4\times z \times$ s.e. where $z$ is the critical value (normal or $t$ distribution depending on the model).  For nonlinear models it is best to get differences in predicted values and the associated confidence interval.  The standard error of such a difference requires matrix calculations but it can be done simply using the R `rms` package.

Comment: Thank you. How does one go about doing this? What kind of statistic do I use?